# Comparar cadenas en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo c++ y la verdad es que no doy con la solución a mi problema:

Quiero crear un programa que pida nombre y edad, y que en caso de que introduzca el nombre correcto (Dan) le salga una cosa, y en caso de que no pues otra.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int edad, nombre, Dan;      
    cout << "introduce tu nombre y tu edad \n";
    cin >> edad >> nombre;    
    if (nombre == Dan && edad >= 18) {
        cout << "Eres el verdadero Dan \n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "No eres el verdadero Dan \n";
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

Comment: Intenta con esto if (nombre == "Dan" && edad >= 18) así definimos que Dan es texto, ya que de otra manera, estaría buscando otra variable la cual no ha sido creada

Comment: ya probaste con alguna validación mas osoea que si nombre es verdadero pasa nuevamente n=dan si es asi pasa

Answer (score 1):

Estás almacenando el nombre en un entero (`int`), el nombre debería ser una cadena de caracteres:

```
int edad;
std::string nombre;
//          ~~~~~~ <-- nombre como objeto cadena de caracteres.

std::cout << "introduce tu nombre \n";
std::cin >> nombre;

std::cout << "introduce tu edad \n";
std::cin >> edad;

if (nombre == "Dan" && edad >= 18) {
//            ~~~~~ <-- cadena de caracteres literal.
    std::cout << "Eres el verdadero Dan \n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "No eres el verdadero Dan \n";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Paula, ya silucione el problema! El muy tonto de mi le estaba dando la variable de nombre en un int, en vez de un string!!